# Make Excel generate a word document based on tick boxes in excel

Tags: excel, ms-word

This is my first question on Stackoverflow so please be gentle. :)

I work in a company where we do a lot of Factory acceptance tests for our equipment. However the equipment differs for each shipment, and therefore so does the Factory acceptance tests. A lot of errors happen when these Factory acceptance test are made, and not updateded to suit the specific equipment.

My idea was to make an excel file where the worker could tick in tick boxes which equipment are present. These tick boxes whould refere to a section of text, which would be included or not included in the Factory acceptance test word document.

I can't really find something that really fits my problem. I hope you can help me.

Comment: If you re-read your question, you'll see that it's pretty broad and not actually a question... you may want to see [ask] and also take the [tour]. Thanks!

Comment: You will need to write some code to do what you are asking. If you are not a developer you might be better off using a survey/questionnaire tool that can generate reports for you...